# How to range over a slice of structs that contain Mutexes in Go

Tags: loops, go, struct, slice, mutex

I am experimenting with Go and trying a variety of things for concurrent state management in a server. Say we have the following:

```golang
type Resource struct {
    data int
}

func (r *Resource) increment () {
    r.data++
}

type Client struct {
    id       int
    resource Resource
    mu       sync.RWMutex
}

type ActiveClients struct {
    clients []Client
    mu      sync.RWMutex
}

func (ac *ActiveClients) add(client Client) {
    ac.mu.Lock()
    defer ac.mu.Unlock()
    if ac.clients == nil {
        ac.clients = make([]Client, 0)
    }
    ac.clients = append(ac.clients, client)
}
```

The `ActiveClients.mu` would be used for reading and writing to the `ActiveClients.clients` slice, and the `Client.mu` would be used for reading from and writing to the `Client.resource`. Now let's say we want to iterate over `ActiveClients.clients` to update one of the resources. The following creates an error:

```golang
func (ac *ActiveClients) addToResource(clientId int) {
    for _, existingClient := range ac.clients {
        if existingClient.id == clientId {
            existingClient.Lock()
            defer existingClient.Unlock()
            existingClient.resource.increment()
        }
    }
}
```

This produces "range var existingClient copies lock: {modulename}.Client contains sync.RWMutex".

How do I range over the slice without copying the lock?

Comment: If there are multiple clients for an ID, then the application should unlock in the loop instead of deferring to function return.  If there's only one client for an ID and order of the clients is not important, then consider using a map keyed by ID instead of a slice.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai good points. Another easy improvement would be to add a return or a break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for _, v := range s` statement assigns the elements of `s` to local variable `v`.  The value is copied. There's no reference semantics

The `go vet` command warns you that the mutex field is copied.  A mutex should not be copied once used.

That's not the only problem in `incrementResource`. The function modifies the copy of client in the local variable, not the client in the slice. Because the local variable is discarded on return from the function, the function `incrementResource` has no effect. Run the program https://go.dev/play/p/kL9GZSL6d2j to see a demonstration of the problem.

Fix the bugs in `incrementResource` by accessing the slice element through a pointer.

```
func (ac *ActiveClients) addToResource(clientId int) {
    for i := range ac.clients {
        existingClient := &ac.clients[i] // existingClient is ptr to slice element
        if existingClient.id == clientId {
            existingClient.Lock()
            defer existingClient.Unlock()
            existingClient.resource.increment()
            fmt.Println("data in addToResource: ", existingClient.resource.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the program with the fix: https://go.dev/play/p/wMSUOjoTauB

The above change fixes the issue in the question, but that's not the only problem with the application. The call to `append` in method `ActiveClients.add` copies the `Client` values when growing the slice. This copy creates a data race on the slice elements and violates the rule that a mutex should not be copied once used.

To fix everything, use a slice of `*Client` instead of `Client`. While we are at it, take advantage of `append`'s handling of `nil` slices.

```
type ActiveClients struct {
    clients []*Client
    mu      sync.RWMutex
}

func (ac *ActiveClients) add(client *Client) {
    ac.mu.Lock()
    defer ac.mu.Unlock()
    ac.clients = append(ac.clients, client)
}
```

Here's the final program: https://go.dev/play/p/miNK90ZDNCu

Comment: Actually, the code I included in my answer works as expected. But this is interesting. I'll have to look more closely at the differences to see why one works and the other does not. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, nvm. We arrived at the same conclusion. Guess that first cup of coffee makes all the difference.

Comment: @JonathanVoss Yes, we have the same end result.  This answer explains the source of the problem and another issue not mentioned in the question or your answer.

Comment: You're right, so I accepted your answer instead of my own. What I ended up doing was using a `map[string]*Client` instead of `[]*Client` because I wanted to ensure unique usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution while writing the question. The solution is to use a slice of pointers rather than a slice of structs -- use `clients []*Client` instead of `clients []Client`:

```golang
type ActiveClients struct {
    clients []*Client
    mu      sync.RWMutex
}

func (ac *ActiveClients) add(client *Client) {
    ac.mu.Lock()
    defer ac.mu.Unlock()
    if ac.clients == nil {
        ac.clients = make([]*Client, 0)
    }
    ac.clients = append(ac.clients, client)
}

func (ac *ActiveClients) incrementResource(clientId int) {
    for _, existingClient := range ac.clients {
        if existingClient.id == clientId {
            existingClient.mu.Lock()
            defer existingClient.mu.Unlock()
            existingClient.resource.increment()
        }
    }
}
```

The full working example is [here](https://pastebin.com/1pAbDnuM). This is probably obvious to experienced Go developers, but I could not find an answer for this specific case, so hopefully this entry will help fellow learners. (Solution is separated from the location of the error in the code, so it is not obvious at first glance without sufficient experience with the memory model.)

Comment: Alternatively, make the mutex field a pointer: mu *sync.RWMutex.